# VBA IF statement - loop through the column A and execute if all rows start only with letters E , S

Tags: excel, vba

Maybe someone knows how can I check with help of VBA if all names in column A necessarily begin with E and S letters? :)

Names in column should mandatorily begin with this letters then code runs further, if names start only with S or only with E, or it contains names which start with any other letter then msgbox should appear and stop the script

Would really appreciate if anyone could help me to find a way to do this via VBA code!!!

I have below code but it doesn't work as expected

```
 lastrowowow = Workbooks(LatestFile).Sheets(1).Columns("A").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row 
     For x = 1 To lastrowowow + 1
    If Left(Workbooks(LatestFile).Sheets(1).Cells(x, 1).Value, 1) = "S" Or Left(Workbooks(LatestFile).Sheets(1).Cells(x, 1).Value, 1) = "E" Then
    If lastrowowow = 1 Then
    AUbeg = 2
    Exit For
            End If
    If Left(Workbooks(LatestFile).Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1).Value, 1) = "S" Then
            AUbeg = x
            Exit For
            End If
            
            If (Workbooks(LatestFile).Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1).Value, 1) = "E" Then
            AUbeg = x
            Exit For
            End If
```

Comment: If you have code, please [edit] your question with it, instead of posting in comments.

Comment: @BigBen - I have such code below, but it check if column A contains names starting with either E or S, 


how can amend it so it will make sure that all names start with E and S not only one of this letters?

Comment: @BigBen - so yeah code is as in edited question but it checks if column has names starting with either S or E, however I need names in column A to start with both E, S letters

Comment: By start with `E` and `S`, do you mean that the names start with `ES`?

Comment: @BigBen unfortunately no, it should be like "Edit", "Sell", "Erase", "Saturday"- then its ok

Comment: Look at using `Split`.

Comment: Split wont work here, names are not in one row, but in column A1="EDIT", A2="SELL", A3="ERASE", A4 ="ERASE"

Comment: Then check if the first letter *isn't* `S` and isn't `E` as you loop.

Comment: Can you please kindly include here an example of script? how it would look like?

Comment: Help please!! )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option, using `Select Case`:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Workbooks(LatestFile).Sheets(1)
...
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastrowowow) 'I am not sure why you are adding 1 in your snippet

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In rng
    Select Case Left$(cell.Value, 1)
        Case "E", "S"
            ' keep processing cell
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Bad value in row " & cell.Row
            Exit Sub
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: that script somehow didn't work, probably lastrowowow needs to be defined

Comment: That's why there's a `...` where you're supposed to insert your existing code that determines `lastrowowow`.

Comment: I used the one from my question : lastrowowow = Workbooks(LatestFile).Sheets(1).Columns("A").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row 
But no result

Comment: @Bignen It worked !!
Dim lastrowowow As Long
lastrowowow = ws.Columns("A").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Msgbox tells me in which cell is "bad value" ! :)

I will add this code to the rest of script and will check how it copes :)

Comment: @ Bigben - how can I stop the whole script running if "Case Else" is met? the code is running fine however I added it in the middle of the whole script and if in case there is a bad value in report it is not showing me msgbox but code keeps running further... :(

Comment: I can't reproduce this. You may want to ask a new question with your revised code.